# How do I figure out what encoding was used to produce some garbled Chinese text?

Tags: python, chinese-locale, mojibake

I have some text which was translated from English into Simplified Chinese. However, when I received the file back, the characters were garbled. So, for example, we have a line that reads "ÎªÁËÓÐÐ§¡¢¸ßÐ§µØÊµÏÖÄ¿±ê£¬Äú×îÐèÒªµÄÊÇÊ²Ã´£¿" rather than containing the Chinese characters I would expect.

I've tried pasting the above string into a Python interpreter, converting it to Unicode, and decoding with various Chinese character sets, to no avail. Does anyone have insight on this? Thank you.

Comment: Do you know what Unicode encoding was used in the original encoding?

Comment: @a_river_in_canada no, that's what the subject of the question asks for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Chardet](https://chardet.github.io):

```
>>> s = "ÎªÁËÓÐÐ§¡¢¸ßÐ§µØÊµÏÖÄ¿±ê£¬Äú×îÐèÒªµÄÊÇÊ²Ã´£¿"
>>> chardet.detect(s.encode('l1'))
{'encoding': 'GB2312', 'confidence': 0.99, 'language': 'Chinese'}
>>> s.encode('l1').decode('gb2312')
'为了有效、高效地实现目标，您最需要的是什么？'
```

Comment: Thank you, Josh! This works, but I am still a little confused about encoding in this context.. Why does `s.encode('l1').decode('gb2312')` work, while `s.encode('utf8').decode('gb2312')` doesn't?

Comment: The text that you gave is a string of characters, which is an interpretation of a string of bytes. In order to determine what those bytes really meant, I had to reverse engineer the string of bytes from your question. It was determined that you used Latin-1 to decode the string of bytes in asking your question, not UTF-8.

Comment: I see, and how did you know that Latin-1 was used to decode the bytes originally?

Comment: Of course, it's possible (though a little strange) that what you actually received was GB2312 text that had been then decoded as Latin-1 and encoded as UTF-8. But you only posted the characters, not the bytes, so there's no way to tell.

Comment: It seemed likely. Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Latin_character_sets_(computing) to see which characters will be found in various encodings. https://ideone.com/UNCBrZ

Comment: Thanks, very helpful.